# Masterpage default dropdown not there

Tags: custom-masterpage

So I've been having an issue, I've loaded up my own html/css/js pages and edited my masterpage, changed the CSS to make the display to be opaque but now for some reason (for testing purposes) I'm trying to change it back to the default, seattle or oslo, but on the screen shot it's not there [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try opening the site in SharePoint designer and going to Master Pages in the left nav. Right click on the master page you want to use and click **Set as Default Master Page**. You may also need to set the master page to the site definition also available in the same menu.